# HTML Javascript problem inserting script tag in live code editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I made live code editor couple days ago, using ace 1.2.9 library.
I had no problems running several guides for my website.
Now I am trying to create this very easy and basic example.
but when i try write the  text  in the text area (where you suppose to insert text for the guides) i get errors by the studio code compiler, and it won't load up.
the problem is when i add this line: (it is in the text area, should not effect the editor code:

`document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript";`

### Code:

```
<body onload="ready()">
    <div id="container">
      <div id="editor"></div>
      <iframe id="iframe" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
    </div>
    <script>
      function update() {
        var idoc = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.document;
        idoc.open();
        idoc.write(editor.getValue());
        idoc.close();
      }
      function setupEditor() {
        window.editor = ace.edit("editor");
        editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
        editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
        editor.setValue(

  `  
     <!-- You can test freely     
       with our live code editor. -->

       <html>
<body>

  <h2>Free code wiki</h2>

<p id="test"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript";
</script>

</body>
</html>



`,
          1
        ); //1 = moves cursor to end

        editor.getSession().on("change", function() {
          update();
        });

        editor.focus();

        editor.setOptions({
          fontSize: "16pt",
          showLineNumbers: false,
          showGutter: false,
          vScrollBarAlwaysVisible: true,
          enableBasicAutocompletion: false,
          enableLiveAutocompletion: false
        });

        editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
        editor.setBehavioursEnabled(false);
      }

      function ready() {
        setupEditor();
        update();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Error:

`Unterminated template literal`

Comment: Please include the full error messages

Comment: Unterminated template literal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the `<script>` tag since it's in a string

Such as

```
<script>
...
<\/script
```

Comment: if i delete it, the guide won't work, since the action will not work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of syntax errors, you have 3  tags  tags missing closing ones. Where does the editor.setValue( closing ) is at?

you have 2 closing  tags.

Where did you copy this code from??

Comment: < body > Scripts and < / html >